# how can i disable an optgroup on change in jquery bootstrap multiselect

Tags: bootstrap-multiselect

I have two multiselect boxes,
On change of the first select box I want to disable some groups of the second select box.

I am using the following code onChange function of the multiselect plugin

```
    $('optgroup[label=MyGroup2]').prop('disabled', true);
```

I dont understand why it is not working, how can I implement it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`refresh` method](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#methods) as follows. The below example demonstrates the usage where the first optgroup will be disabled by the corresponding button, however, the example can easily be adapted to your concrete case of manipulating the optgroups in the `onChange` option. Note that the state of the options (i.e. whether selected or not) is preserved after disabling the optgroup, so you might want to deselect the options first.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#multiselect').multiselect();
        
        $("#multiselect-disable-optgroup1").on('click', function() {
            $('#multiselect optgroup#optgroup1').prop('disabled', true);
            $('#multiselect').multiselect('refresh');
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="multiselect" multiple="multiple">
        <optgroup label="Group 1" id="optgroup1">
            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Group 2">
            <option value="4">Option 4</option>
            <option value="5">Option 5</option>
            <option value="6">Option 6</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
    <button id="multiselect-disable-optgroup1">Disable Group 1</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you need to deactivate all other groups =)

```
 <select id="multiselect" multiple="multiple">
    <optgroup label="Group 1" id="optgroup1">
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Group 2" id="optgroup2">
        <option value="4">Option 4</option>
        <option value="5">Option 5</option>
        <option value="6">Option 6</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Script:

```
BlaBlaVar = function(selector) {
                if ($(selector + ' option:selected').length) {
                    selectedGroupId = $(selector + ' option:selected').parent().attr('id');
                    $(selector + ' :not(#' + selectedGroupId + ') option').prop('disabled', true);
                } else {
                    $(selector + ' option').prop('disabled', false);
                }
            };

BlaBlaVar('#multiselect');
$('#multiselect').multiselect('refresh');
```

Answer (score 0):

Now, in the year 2020, the solution for the current bootstrap multi-select version doesn't work. I disable/enable the optgroup with this code:

`$("b:contains(text-in-the-opt-group)").prev().attr('disabled', true/false);`